# how add new data to data grid view without delete data C#?

Tags: c#

hello guys  need to put data on data grid view without delete this my code but this code give me only last item in list box

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        
 {
    textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();               
            
    dataGridView1.DataSource = cls_all.Get_Test3(Convert.ToSingle(textBox1.Text));
 }
```

tried this code

```
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cls_all.Get_Test3(Convert.ToSingle(textBox1.Text)));
```

and  get this msg System.InvalidOperationException: 'Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.'

need way to put data without delete data grid view any help with it

Comment: Hi,
I think 
dataGridView1.DataSource 
should not be inside the for loop, what do you get when you put 

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cls_all.Get_Test3(Convert.ToSingle(textBox1.Text)));

inside the loop?

Comment: this msg : System.InvalidOperationException: 'Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DataTable instead of directly trying to add rows to a grid.

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("MyColumn", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
   textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items[i].ToString(); // I do not know why you need this 
   dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { listBox1.Items[i].ToString()});
}
dataGridView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```